# Не работает проект C# с базой данных при переносе

Tags: c#, база-данных

Писал программу в среде разработки Visual Studio 2013 
Перенес на Visual Studio 2015 на другой ноутбук.
Проект не компилируется. 
В программе используются mdf

Как то разок выскочила ошибка

> The Data Source value in the connection string specifies an instance of SQL Server that is not installed" or "LocalDB instance does not exist

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: «Проект не компилируется» — а сообщение компилятора об ошибке вы нам не доверите?

Comment: @VladD - Вы все время ищете каких-то легких путей :) - то сообщение компилятора, то Exception.Message Вам подавай.

Answer (score 1):

В ошибке дословно написано

- или у вас не установлен SQL Server вообще. Установите.
- или у вас не создан инсанс LocalDB - создайте вызовом

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" create instancename
```

где instancename - имя инстанса из вашей строки соединения - оно в ней скорее всего вписано как (localdb)\instancename.

Comment: Можно так сказать для чайника, что значит создать вызовом. Exeшник по указанному вами пути есть. Где создать вызовом? и как?

Comment: @DevilScream посмотреть имя инстанса в конфиге программы, открыть cmd, вписать команду из ответа, подставив имя инстанса

Comment: @PashaPash♦  Да имя localdb. Если все правильно понял то в cmd  я я создаю вызовом подставив имя инстанса. После зашел в программу сделал рефреш на бд выскочила таже ошибка

Comment: @DevilScream имя - не localdb. имя - то, что написано после `(localdb)`.  Например, если там написано `(localdb)\v11.0` - то имя - `v11.0`